# Do I need a powerful discrete video card for Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, computer-hardware, gpu

I have my computer and it doesn't have a separate video card. Do i need a video card to install Photoshop? Or is there any version of Photoshop that doesn't require to a separate video card?

Comment: @vlumi Even though we call it a "graphics card", of course an integrated GPU isn't a *card* at all.